How to remove the link that references python@3.10 after remove manually Python
I manually deleted python3 from the macBook Air.
When I enter the python3 --version command I get the following message in the terminal,
-bash: python3: command not found

however when I execute the pip3 --version command the path name of pip3 is displayed.
-bash: /usr/local/bin/pip3: /usr/local/opt/python@3.10/bin/python3.10: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

How to remove the link that references python@3.10?
$ brew list
==> Formulae
autoconf    freetype    libffi      libtool     mpdecimal    readline
automake    gdbm        libgit2@1.7 lz4     mpfr        spatialindex
ca-certificates gettext     libmpc      lzip        openssl@3   sqlite
cmake       gmp     libpng      m4      pcre2       xz
fontconfig  isl     libssh2     make    pkg-config  zstd

==> Casks
010-editor      dbeaver-community   xquartz
$ which pip3
/usr/local/bin/pip3
$ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
$ which python3
$ 

The output of the python --V is:
$ python -V
Python 2.7.10

The output of the pip -V is:
$ pip -V
-bash: /usr/local/bin/pip: /usr/local/opt/python@3.10/bin/python3.10: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

I did try with the rm command:
$ rm -fr /usr/local/opt/python@3.10
$ pip -V
-bash: /usr/local/bin/pip: /usr/local/opt/python@3.10/bin/python3.10: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Second approach using sudo rm:
$ sudo rm -fr /usr/local/opt/python@3.10
Password:
$ pip -V
-bash: /usr/local/bin/pip: /usr/local/opt/python@3.10/bin/python3.10: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

The computer I use is a MacBook Air, with macOS Sierra version 10.12.6
Thanks,

how did you install python in you mac did you installed with installer or did you use homebrew??

@nabin - I don't remember. But I think because of the format of the link I did it with homebrew

can you also paste the output of python -V i know your python 3 is uninstalled, and i will list all the commands in answer section

rm -fr /usr/local/opt/python@3.10 will remove that sub-tree if that is what you want.  If you are not sure either mv it or backup it before you delete it.

@nabin - it is done.  I have included the output for python -V and pip -V as additional reference.

just use this for pip sudo rm /usr/local/bin/pip like wise for pip3 you can do sudo rm /usr/local/bin/pip3

@Allan - The rm command does not work. PS. I'm not sure whether the reference to the link is included in some configuration .sh file...the question is in which file .. thinking out loud (finger on the air).

You would need to run that as root (sudo)  on Linux.  I know nothing about MacOS.  Update question with data on why rm didn't work.

@Allan. Just updated.

@Allan- I will try with sudo.

Do you have a working python3 on your system?  If not can you install one?

rm would have complained if it didn't work

@Allan- After executing the rm command, the operating system simply does not display any logs in the console. I'm going to install Python 3.10 and see how the python -V and pip -V commands behave.

Have you tried using brew unlink?

@sytech- The brew list command does not include the cellar for python@3.10 so the command has no effect. Note: $ brew unlink python@3.10
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10

for pip:
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/pip

for pip3:
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/pip3

lastly open your .bash_profile or .zshrc in nano editor and check for similar line as follows:
export PATH=.../python3...

and remove it , save it and restart the shell and your issue will be fixed.
#EDITED#
if you want to remove python3 installed with brew then do following steps:
brew list | grep python
brew uninstall --force python
brew cleanup

and follow top steps to remove symlink
if you want to remove python 3 installed from official python installer the do the following:
sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/python3
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/pip3


I'm interested in deleting all references to Python 3.10, I'm going to try your recommendation. I won't install Python 3.10 yet.

did you do above steps?? @Ramiro

i have put edited section but please make sure to ask in another question if your first question is answerd is fullfilled in this. as per stackoerflow, one question is expected to be answerd in that context not the addtional one to keep the context intact as per the mods.@Ramiro

Yes, I did... all done ... how ever pip -V still displaying the message "/usr/local/opt/python@3.10/bin/python3.10: bad interpreter: No such file or directory"

see the error message /usr/local/opt/python@3.10/bin/python3.10: bad interpreter: No such file or directory now you need to run the same command in /usr/local/opt/ directory sudo rm -rf /usr/local/opt/pip. i thought you got the idea how we need to remove symlink with my example
